# Azure functions messing up gzipped POST data

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, express, azure-functions

Currently i'm implementing a webhook which states that the request sent to the configured endpoint will be gzipped, and i'm experiencing a weird bug with that.

I created a middleware to handle de gunzip of the request data:

```js
  const buffer: Buffer[] = [];

    request
      .on("data", (chunk) => {
        buffer.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        const concatBuff: Buffer = Buffer.concat(buffer);

        zlib.gunzip(concatBuff, (err, buff) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("gunzip err", err);
            return next(err);
          }
          request.body = buff.toString();
          next();
        });
      });
```

I added this middleware before all the other body parser middlewares to avoid any incompatibility with that.

So i'm testing it with this curl command:

```
cat webhook.txt | gzip | curl -v -i --data-binary @- -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:3334
```

In this server, which uses `azure-function-express`, i'm getting this error:

```
[1/9/2020 22:36:21] gunzip err Error: incorrect header check
[1/9/2020 22:36:21]     at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:170:17) {
[1/9/2020 22:36:21]   errno: -3,
[1/9/2020 22:36:21]   code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
[1/9/2020 22:36:21] }
[1/9/2020 22:36:21]
```

it seems that the error is caused because the header is not the "magical number" of a gzip file:

<Buffer **1f ef bf bd 08** 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 4e 5f 00 03 ef bf bd 5d 6d 73 db b8 11 ef bf bd ef b
f bd 5f ef bf bd e1 97 bb 6b 7d 16 ef bf bd 77 ef bf bd 73 ef ... 4589 more bytes>

But here is the weird thing, i created a new express application to test this using the exactly same curl, and it works perfectly in there, so it seems that there is some problem with the **createAzureFunctionHandler**, or i'm missing out something.

Have you guys experienced any of those problems using Azure functions??

Any idea of what is Azure messing up with the gzip data??

Comment: Can you also set `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header in your curl request and check

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT It seems that changing it fix the error, however i have no control of the Conent-Type because is sent by another system.
Do you have any idea of why setting it as application/json crashes?

Comment: Technically, setting Content-Type as `application/octet-stream` means "I have no idea what this binary is all about, take it as you get and don't mess with it".  In Function http trigger, if the content-type is not `application/octet-stream` or starts with "multipart", it tries to read as string where the encoding might get messed up if not specified correctly. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/294) around this. For your case, try setting ` "dataType": "binary"` in the http trigger in your function.json. (1/2)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#bindings-data-type (2/2)

Comment: I just got an answer from Azure, they told me to use an Azure proxy, so i got it working with that

Comment: If i'm not mistaken compression is to compress responses, i wanted to decompress a request body sent to me from a webhook, anywat thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer from the Azure team, they recommend me to set a proxy inside `proxies.json` as a workaround, so if anyone is having the same issue you can just set a new proxy to override the `Content-Type`.

In my case i was always expecting a gzipped json, so maybe if you don't know beforehand which type is this wouldn't work for you.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "RequireContentType": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/api/HttpTrigger"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://proxy-example.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger",
            "requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.headers.content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "backend.request.headers.request-content-type": "'{request.headers.content-type}'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```